# Is it possible to catch and retry exceptions thrown by a ChunkListener in Spring Batch?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

I configured the CustomChunkListener. I created to check the status of redis Distributed lock and throw an Custom Exception if it is locked.

In Step, of Custom Exception is caught with fault Tolerant, Step is configured to be re-executed up to 3 times.

However, FaultTolerantStepBuilder delegates ChunkListener to TerminateOnExceptionChunkListenerDelegate class and throws FatalStepExecutionException.
Unable to catch CustomException

my code sample.

```
public Class MyBatchConfig {

    public Step MyBatchStep() {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("refineCarStatusStep")
                                    .<I, O>chunk(CHUNK_SIZE)
                                    .reader(MyItemReader())
                                    .processor(MyItemProcessor())
                                    .writer(MyItemWriter())
                                    .faultTolerant()
                                    .retry(CustomException.class)
                                    .retryLimit(3)
                                    .listener(new CustomChunkListener())
                                    .build();
    }
}

public class CustomChunkListener implements ChunkListener {

    @Override
    public void beforeChunk(ChunkContext context) {
        // example. redis Distributed lock check
        if(isLocked) {
            throw new CustomException();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void afterChunk(ChunkContext context) {
        unlock();
    }

    @Override
    public void afterChunkError(ChunkContext context) {
        unlock();
    }
}
```

How can I throw, catch and retry an exception before the start of the chunk?

Answer (score 0):

No, that is not possible. ChunkListeners shouldn't throw exceptions and expect continued processing. Exceptions must be handled in the implementation or the step will terminate. This is mentioned in the javadoc of `TerminateOnExceptionChunkListenerDelegate`, but this class is private.

I created [this issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/issues/4384) to update the documentation accordingly.

Comment: So, can't the chunk throw an exception before the start and should it throw an exception before step or read?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand that question. What do you mean by `can't the chunk throw an exception before the start`? We are talking about the chunk listener here, not the chunk. The ChunkListener is not expected to throw exceptions, you can see it from method signatures.

Comment: sorry, I'm not fluent in English
I used a chunklistener to check some logic before the chunk starts and throw an exception if it fails.
And if it fails, I want that chunk to be executed again.

Comment: What you are suggesting would cause a deadlock. And it is not possible with exception as @MahmoudBenHassine said. But you can just wait a while in the listener then retry if locked and just return when unlocked. You can do it in a loop N times.